# ESM complains on the serverless-webpack/lib/validate.js using require

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules, serverless-webpack-plugin

I have a dependency to serevrless-webpack 5.7.1 and I have "type": "module" in the package.json. When I try to deploy the code using serverless, it complains on the use of require in serverless-webpack/lib/validate.js in which I do not have the control.

How can I mitigate this error?

Comment: This can help you https://dev.to/joostschuur/using-pure-esm-npm-packages-in-serverless-webpack-bundles-apd